# Stackoverflow's tagging system recreated using ruby on rails active record association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am wondering about how StackOverflow's tagging system works.

Stackoverflow has `Question` model and `Tag` model.

`Question` belongs to multiple `tags` like Javascript, Ruby etc.

`Tag` has many `questions` like [questions on Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [questions on Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby).

How would you set up the database tables to reflect this relationship?

---

My current solution.

`Question` has an attribute called `tags`. `tags` contains a list of integers referring to different `Tag` models. This way is **really bad** when you are trying to query all the questions for a tag model, since you have to go through a list for every question model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a normal, classical, standard many-to-many association:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association